# Can $Cov(X,Y^2)=0$ if $Corr(X,Y)$ is negative?

Tags: correlation, covariance

Basically the title. I have fiddled around with the various forms of $Cov(X,Y^{2})$ but to no avail. At this point if I had to guess, I would say it's possible [?} Thanks.

EDIT: the original question is proving whether the following statement is true or false:

$\text{If}\;Corr(X,Y)<0, \text{then}\; Cov(X,Y^2)\; \text{must be}\; 0 $

Comment: For an example with random variables, let $X$ have symmetric distribution around $0$ and set $Y=-X.$  Here, the correlation of $-1$ is the most negative possible but the symmetry of the distribution of $X$ shows the covariance is exactly zero.  This example might give you some insight into how these quantities can be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be possible?  Sure.  Here is an example to prove it is possible.

```
x<-seq(-3,3)
y<-seq(3,-3)

cor(x,y)
>>>-1
cov(x,y^2)
>>>0
```

Comment: Therefore the statement "given Corr(X,Y)<0, Cov(X,Y^2) =0" is false? I edited my question to include this btw

Comment: I've just provided an example in which corr<0 but cov=0, so yes it is possible.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I reworded the statement in the question's EDIT